# Typescript prevent objects being added to array of objects if an object's boolean property is true

Tags: typescript, oop, generics

I have tried finding the solution but I can't seem to find out how in generics one can prevent an object being included into an array on base of property value.

I was given following exercise in an online interview where within an hour I was supposed to develop following:

A zoo where there are five animals and two birds are there, two zoo keepers stay night time and 4 zoo keepers in the morning.Only norman is allowed to go into tiger’s cage

I started working on it but got stuck at index.ts where I am able to do following:
lion.assignHandler(john);
but I want typescript to prevent me adding john to lion instead it is letting me. I want only norman and other employees who are in lion's handlers and only handlers employees whose _dangerHandler property is true should be allowed.

Sandbox at the following: https://codesandbox.io/s/zoo-example-yi3op

```
export default interface Dangerous {
    canBeHandledBy(employees: Employee[]): void;
}

import Employee from "./Employee";

export default class Animal {
    private _handlers: Employee[] = [];
    constructor(private _name: string){}
    public get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
    public get handlers(): Employee[] {
        return this._handlers;
    }
    public set handlers(employees: Employee[]) {
        this._handlers = employees;
    }
    public assignHandler(employee: Employee): void {
        this._handlers.push(employee);
    }
}

export default class Employee {
    constructor(private _name: string, private _gender: Gender, private _employeeTitle: EmployeeTitle, private _dangerHandler: boolean = false) {}
    public get name():string {
        return this._name;
    }
    public get gender(): Gender {
        return this._gender;
    }
    public get isDangerHandler(): boolean {
        return this._dangerHandler;
    }
    public get title(): EmployeeTitle {
        return this._employeeTitle;
    }
    public set title(title: EmployeeTitle){
        this._employeeTitle = title;
    }
}


export default class Lion extends Animal implements Dangerous {
    constructor(_name: string) {
        super(_name)
    }
    
    canBeHandledBy(employees: Employee[]): void {        
        try {
            const ordinaryEmployees = employees.filter(emp => !emp.isDangerHandler);
            if(ordinaryEmployees.length >0 ){
                throw new Error('Ordinary meployees not allowed to handle Lion');
            }
            this.handlers = employees;
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

in app.js

I want typescript to prevent me adding john to lion instead it is letting me.

```
const norman:Employee = new Employee("norman", Gender.MALE, EmployeeTitle.ZOOKEEPER, true);
const john:Employee = new Employee("john", Gender.MALE, EmployeeTitle.ZOOKEEPER);

const lion = new Lion("zumba");
lion.assignHandler(john)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified your example, but you can take a inspiration from following modelling and see if it suits you:

```js
type TypeOfAnimal = 'Dangerous' | 'Harmless'

interface Animal<T extends TypeOfAnimal> {
  name: string
  assignHandler: (handler: Employee<T>) => void
}

class Lion implements Animal<'Dangerous'> {
  constructor(readonly name: string) {}
  assignHandler(handler: Employee<'Dangerous'>) {
    console.log(handler)
  }
}

class Employee<T extends TypeOfAnimal> {
  constructor(readonly name: string, readonly canHandle: T) {}
}

const norman = new Employee('Norman', 'Dangerous')
const john = new Employee('John', 'Harmless')

const lion: Lion = new Lion('Zumba')

lion.assignHandler(norman) // compiles
lion.assignHandler(john) // does not compile
```

Comment: Thanks Pritam, this is exactly I wanted to see, i really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: There is issue though now I cannot add it zoo any animal.
`
class Zoo {

    private _animals: Array<Animal<TypeOfAnimal>> = [];

    constructor(private _name: string){}

    public addAnimal(animal: Animal<TypeOfAnimal>):void {
        this._animals.push(animal);
    }
}

const lion: Lion = new Lion('Zumba')

lion.assignHandler(norman) // compiles

const zoo  = new Zoo('Georgia Zoo');

zoo.addAnimal(lion);
`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update `assignhandler()` in `Animal.ts` to check if the `employee` passed into the method has the `isDangerHandler` attribute set to `True`.

```
public assignHandler(employee: Employee): void {
  if (employee.isDangerHandler) {
    this._handlers.push(employee);
  }
}
```

Comment: So is there no way in generics we can have the property being checked against if instance is getting added to array of objects and typescript can see the property on that object is set to true. what i wanted was typescript not allowing me to add the employee object which has isDangerHandler set to true

Comment: `Generics` can help you guard against adding a wrong `type`, hence ensuring your code is `type-safe`. In your example, `isDangerHandler` is an `attribute`, and `generics` does not deal with `attributes`.

Comment: Thanks codemax, I see what you are saying and now i get it.